# jax-ws service returns arraylist

Tags: java, web-services, jpa, arraylist, jax-ws

```
@Entity
public class School {

    @Id
    private int Id;
    private String schoolName;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "schoolId")  
    private List<Student> students;

    //....  get and set methods
}


@Entity
public class Student {

    @Id
    private int Id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    @JoinColumn()
    @ManyToOne
    private School schoolId;

    //....  get and set methods
}
```

I have this entities in my **maven web project**. I am using jpa framework.

```
@WebService
public class MyService {
    @WebMethod
    public List<School> getSchoolInfo()
    {
        List<School> schools=getSchoolListFromDb();
        //schools liste has records, and each school has own student list
        return schools;
    }
}
```

I wrote this getSchoolInfos method to share with a jax-ws service. I got the result when I use my return Type as School[]. But I want to use List<> type.

I wanted to use the axis service but I couldn't run axis in maven web project.

What should I do? Which web service technology I should use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found similar problems with Weblogic proprietary webservice technologies and CXF.  My advice is to surrender and write an interface returning `School[]`.  Just do this to keep working all your current code:

Server side

```
public School[] whatever() {
   List<School> list = ...
   ...
   return list.toArray(new School[list.size()]);
}
```

Client side

```
public void myClient() {
   WhateverProxy myProxy = ...
   ...
   List<School> list = Arrays.asList(myProxy.whatever());
   ...
}
```

This way your webservice technology is happy and creates a very simple WSDL, and you continue working with much more useful `List` interfaces.  Consider it a highway toll or something like that